# iOS get substring from a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'v a string like - `NSString * str = @"a. System discharges to the ground or to surface waters\n\nb. System causes sewage backup in structure\n\nc. “Black Soil” above system or drain field\n\n\nd. Ponding or puddles around tank, distribution boxes, or drain field"` and want some specific substring from str for e.g. **b. System causes sewage backup in structure**
i have tried

```
NSRange r1 = [str rangeOfString:@"b. "];
    NSString* substr = [str substringFromIndex:r1.location];
    NSString* s1 = [substr stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

but i got whole string starting from **b. System....**
What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's normal. You're substringing from `r1.location` to the end of the `NSString`. You need to look for the next "\n" to `substringWithRange`, or maybe use a `NSRegularExpression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
NSRange r1 = [str rangeOfString:@"b. "];
NSString *substr = [str substringFromIndex:r1.location];
NSRange r2 = [substr rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *s1 = [substr substringToIndex:r2.location];
```

Comment: Its probably not right to have the new line character hard coded as "\n"

Comment: No, it will give you the first occurence of that, and since it is called on `substr`, then you indeed need the first occurence. @OzairKafray you are right, I've edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have your starting point right but you also need to make it right at the end point. This code might help you. Though this mayn't be the exact thing that you might be looking for, it will surely help you in getting the desired result.

```
NSString *badStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[response bytes]];
NSString *goodStr = [badStr substringFromIndex:76];
NSString *finalStr = [goodStr substringToIndex:[goodStr length]-9];
```

Basically, this code removes the unwanted characters from the beginning as well as from the ending of the string.

Hope this helps.